# How to transfer data between javascript and ASP.NET server program

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am trying to capture data entered by a user through javascript running on my webpage, then transfer that data to ASP.NET server program that actually created that webpage.

So I created a asp:HiddenField as follows:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="BusesFromDrawing" runat="server" />
```

And in the javascript I set its value (and make sure it's set by displaying it in a div).
Then in my C# server application I write this in a button handler - it is supposed to simply take the data from the hidden field and paste it in a textbox.

```
string allconfigs = BusesFromDrawing.Value;
tb3.Text = allconfigs;
```

and tb3 has the following declaration:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tb3" Text="Default Text" runat="server" />
```

However, I always end up with an empty string replacing "Default Text" even though I put some text in the hidden field and it shows up in the javascript portion.

Comment: How do you know your javascript update the hidden field correctly?

Comment: After setting the value of the hidden field, I query its value again and display it in a text box in javascript. It displays correctly.

Comment: The problem seems to be that this update is somehow not visible to the server program, but visible to the javascript client.

Comment: Found the problem.. in javascript I have to set the hidden field by using a lower-case "value" but when I read it in C# I have to ask for the upper-case "Value" pffftttt!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to be in the javascript portion, when setting the hiddenfield I was using:

```
BusesFromDrawingField.Value = somestring
```

I just needed to use a lower-case 'v':

```
BusesFromDrawingField.value = sometring
```

even though in C# I use an upper-case 'V' when asking for the value!